# Javascript error: cannot find module imported

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was trying to import a module 'CryptographyClient' from a given directory, it was successful in typescript. However, after I compiled the code into javascript, I got an error saying it cannot find module.
Below is my typescript code:

```
import { CryptographyClient } from "C:/Users/fredg/Desktop/AzureSDK-master/AzureSDK-master/Node/sample/node_modules/@azure/keyvault-keys/src/cryptographyClient";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

async function main(): Promise<void> {
  // DefaultAzureCredential expects the following three environment variables:
  // - AZURE_TENANT_ID: The tenant ID in Azure Active Directory
  // - AZURE_CLIENT_ID: The application (client) ID registered in the AAD tenant
  // - AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: The client secret for the registered application
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

  const vaultName = process.env["KEYVAULT_NAME"] || "keyvault-js"
  const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

  // Connection to Azure Key Vault
  const client = new KeysClient(url, credential);

  let keyName = "localWorkKey";

  // Connection to Azure Key Vault Cryptography functionality
  let myWorkKey = await client.createKey(keyName, "RSA");

  const cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(url, myWorkKey.keyMaterial!.kid!, credential);

  // Sign and Verify
  const signatureValue = "MySignature";
  let hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");

  hash.update(signatureValue);
  let digest = hash.digest();
  console.log("digest: ", digest);

  const signature = await cryptoClient.sign("RS256", digest);
  console.log("sign result: ", signature);

  const verifyResult = await cryptoClient.verify("RS256", digest, signature.result);
  console.log("verify result: ", verifyResult);

  // Encrypt and decrypt
  const encrypt = await cryptoClient.encrypt("RSA1_5", Buffer.from("My Message"));
  console.log("encrypt result: ", encrypt);

  const decrypt = await cryptoClient.decrypt("RSA1_5", encrypt.result);
  console.log("decrypt: ", decrypt.result.toString());

  // Wrap and unwrap
  const wrapped = await cryptoClient.wrapKey("RSA-OAEP", Buffer.from("My Message"));
  console.log("wrap result: ", wrapped);

  const unwrapped = await cryptoClient.unwrapKey("RSA-OAEP", wrapped.result);
  console.log("unwrap result: ", unwrapped);

  await client.deleteKey(keyName);
}
main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("error code: ", err.code);
  console.log("error message: ", err.message);
  console.log("error stack: ", err.stack);
});
```

I expected the code to run smoothly, however in the terminal I got an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:/Users/fredg/Desktop/AzureSDK-master/AzureSDK-master/Node/sample/node_modules/@azure/keyvault-keys/src/cryptographyClient'
```

Comment: Try including the `.js` file extension on `cryptographyClient`

Comment: Try using relative imports instead of absolute ones.

Comment: using the absolute imports is very dangerous

Comment: @phuzi the 'cryptographyClient' file was a '.ts' file, I tried to add '.ts' extension and I got reminded that I don't need to.

Comment: Why don't you import it as specified in the documentation? `import { CryptographyClient } from "@azure/keyvault-keys";`

Comment: @Tri Phan Thanks a lot for the reminder, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use relative imports instead of absolute ones. Just import from the package:

`import { CryptographyClient } from "@azure/keyvault-keys";`

Comment: Acutually , I ran the 
```npm install @azure/keyvault-keys@4.0.0-preview.2``` 
command and then when I tried 
```import { CryptographyClient } from "@azure/keyvault-keys";```
 I got an error message saying that 
```Module '"../../../../../../../../Users/fredg/Desktop/AzureSDK-master/AzureSDK-master/Node/sample/node_modules/@azure/keyvault-keys/types/keyvault-keys"' has no exported member 'CryptographyClient'.``` 
So I searched for the missing modules on github and tried to add them in the correct directories myself. 
Now I realised that it is a very bad idea.

Comment: I should have waited for them to modify the package instead of trying to find out what is missing, I am still learning on this programming language, thanks a lot for your help.